# "Know Thyself" Program

Tags: code-golf, quine, text-processing

## Challenge

Write a program that takes as input a text and output "That's me!" if the input is equal to the program own source code, and "That's not me!" otherwise.

## Notes

- This is codegolf, in each programming language the shortest program wins.
- The input can be taken from program arguments or function argument, and the ouput can be printed or given as a return value.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Comment: I've also VTC as a duplicate, although it may not be *that simple* to port *any* answer from that challenge to this one. Grounds for keeping this variant?

Comment: @JonathanAllan The differences I can see aren't enough IMO, it's very unlikely that a solution from that challenge can't easily change its input source while its language is able to compete here, and the difference in the output strings is negligible. Also, there's a standard "template" for quines in most languages that's probably already used in the other challenge. I have a hammer too, though.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this challenge as I feel that, given that it's a [tag:quine] challenge, the difference between outputting `true`/anything and outputting 1 of 2 strings make this sufficiently different. Yes, there will be a few solutions to the dupe target that can be trivially modified to be competitive here but there will also be solutions that will need to take a different approach.

Comment: I don't see this as sufficiently different to merit being left open. Looking at the answers to the other challenges, the vast majority of them (at least those in languages I understand) are payload-capable quines to which one could add code to print specified strings, which is enough to make a duplicate. Additionally, this appears to be taking a pre-existing challenge with flexible IO and adding a cumbersome output format, which is a [thing to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/46076)